# Nested class serialization

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, deserialization

I'd like to serialize (in JSON format) a list of object where each object has a property of another type of object. This is what I've got so far:

```
[DataContract]
public class Person{

   [DataMember]
   public string Name { get; set; }
   [DataMember]
   public Address FullAddress { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Address {
   private readonly byte[] _foo;
   private ulong _value;

   public byte[] Foo { get { return (byte[]) _foo.Clone(); }}

   public ulong Value { get { return _value; } set { return _value; }}

   public Address(byte [] bytes){
      _foo = new byte[bytes.Length];
      Array.Copy(bytes, _foo, bytes.Length);

      foreach(byte b in _foo){
        _value |= b; // I do some bit manipulation here and modify the _value
      }

   }

   public MacAddress() // added this otherwise I get an exception
   {

   }
}
```

this is how I'm serializing and deserializing:

```
public class MyJson{

    public MyJson(){
      var list = new List<Person>{ /* added a bunch of person here */ };
      var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
      string json = serializer.Serialize(list);
      // serialization works fine


      var desList = serializer.Deserialize<IList<Person>>(json);

      // the deserialization doesn't properly deserialize Address property.

   }
}
```

As commented above, the serialization works fine but deserialization doesn't deserialize Address properly. I get a number for **Value** property (as expected) but not for **Foo** (I know it is missing a setter but what if, for some reason, I cannot put a setter?).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

I don't use JSon but if it works like XML serialization I'm guessing it has to do with the fact that `Foo` doesn't have a setter.  You may need to create a custom serialization class that uses the constructor to set `Foo`.  Others may be able to provide more specifics.

Comment: You are right, having a setter for Foo does work. But I'm wondering if there is any other way to make it work in the case of absence of a setter.